# Не оптимизируется путь в google maps

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

Пишу android приложение с картой от google. Написал код для запроса маршрута с использованием ***"google-maps-services:0.2.7"***.
Промежуточные точки передаются строкой, параметр оптимизации пути указан, но маршрут все равно строится по последовательности указания точек.

Код запроса:

```
        String waypointsString = "";
        for(int i = 0; markersList.size() > i; i++){
            waypointsString += markersList.get(i).latitude + "," + markersList.get(i).longitude + "|";
        }

        String cur_pos_coords = latitude + "," + longitude;
        GeoApiContext geoApiContext = new GeoApiContext.Builder()
                .apiKey(mapsApiKey)
                .build();
        DirectionsResult result = null;
        try {
            result = DirectionsApi.newRequest(geoApiContext)
                    .mode(TravelMode.WALKING)
                    .origin(cur_pos_coords)//Место старта
                    .destination(cur_pos_coords)//Пункт назначения
                    //.waypoints(markersList.get(0).latitude + "," + markersList.get(0).longitude+ "|"+ markersList.get(1).latitude + "," + markersList.get(1).longitude+"|"+markersList.get(2).latitude + "," + markersList.get(2).longitude)
                    .waypoints(waypointsString)
                    .optimizeWaypoints(true)
                    .language("ru")
                    .await();
        } catch (InterruptedException | IOException | ApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Получаю ответ, записываю порядок в массив, но порядок не изменился, то бишь оптимизации пути не было

```
int[] ar = result.routes[0].waypointOrder;
        for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
            Log.d("Point #" + i, "" + ar[i]);
            addMarker(markersList.get(ar[i]).latitude, markersList.get(ar[i]).longitude, i, "Задача №" + ar[i]);
        }
```

Заранее спасибо за ответы.

> **UPD**

Решение было найдено путем добавления в начало к строке с координатами отрывка ***"optimize:true|"*** и комментирования строки вызова метода ***.optimizeWaypoints(true)***. В итоге у нас получился такой вызов:

```
 result = DirectionsApi.newRequest(geoApiContext)
                    .mode(TravelMode.WALKING)
                    .origin(cur_pos_coords)//Место старта
                    .destination(cur_pos_coords)//Пункт назначения
                    .waypoints("optimize:true|" + waypointsString)
                    //.optimizeWaypoints(true)
                    .await();
```

Comment: При этом вы уверены, что есть более оптимальный маршрут по этим точкам?

Comment: покажите вывод из result? особенно из geocoder_status

Comment: Оптимальный маршрут есть, так как одна из точек находится слишком далеко от места старта.

Comment: @SergeMarkov ответ положительный. Дело запрос проверил прямой ссылкой в хроме, ответ пришел с оптимизированными точками